# Multiple SetTimeouts execute together

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I recently try to learn Webdesign and wanted to do a simple fadeout of an image with JavaScript. I Know there is an easier way with jQuery and after some time with this problem i used that way, but i stumbles across it  and want to unterstand why this happens.

To break down the process lets say I have an image and want it to reduce its opacity every 0.1 seconds. Therefore I used a for loop and called a fade function with SetTimeout(fade,100). But every of the 10 loops are executed at the same time. I tried it even more simple with

```
setTimeout(fade,100);
setTimeout(fade,100); ....
```

Even then all 10 instances of the funtion get executed at once. 
So for future projects: why is that and is there a possible workaround?

Thank you very much

Comment: `setInterval`..?

Comment: It seems like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Most probably, you don't need to call it many times. Show your `fade` method implementation, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use setInterval.

```
setInterval(fade,100);
```

setInterval is for a repetitive task. It will keep running. Makes sure you clear interval once you are done to prevent memory leakage.

You are using a for loop, which is not the correct way.

Assume at the current instant the time is: 0

You ran a for loop and created 5 setTimeouts. It takes some time to create this but you can't notice it.

So, each setTimeout should execute after 100 ms.

But they are created at:

```
 1. 0.000000001
 2. 0.000000002
 3. 0.000000003
 4. 0.000000004
 5. 0.000000005
```

And they will call the callback after:

```
 1. 100.000000001
 2. 100.000000002
 3. 100.000000003
 4. 100.000000004
 5. 100.000000005
```

(Just for demonstration)

So, you are not going to notice them and these (setTimeout and setInterval) are not absolute. They make take longer.

Hope it helps. :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the `event loop`. To thoroughly understand this behaviour you have to understand all stages of event loop and especially how `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is handled

MDN article on event loop
[MDN event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Rising stack article will help you in getting a clear understanding of event loop along with micro and macro task

[rising stack event loop explained](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-understanding-node-js-event-loop/)

In nutshell all `setTimeout` gets processed in same `tick` of the loop.

Also for your case `setInterval` is much better

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve it. As others have suggested you can use `setInterval` or use `setTimeout` to call recursively. If you must use `for` loop for some reason, that is also possible.

The basic idea is your call to second `setTimeout` must be given only after the first execution of `fade` function or otherwise increase the timeout period between successive calls to `setTimeout`.

```js
//\//\//\// method 1
function fadeRecur() {
  var d1 = document.querySelector( ".d1" );
  if(d1.style.opacity == '') d1.style.opacity = 1;
  //console.log(d1.style.opacity);
  if(d1.style.opacity > 0) {
    d1.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    setTimeout(fadeRecur, 100);
  }
}
setTimeout(fadeRecur, 100);

//\//\//\// method 2
var fsi;

function fadeInter() {
  var d2 = document.querySelector( ".d2" );
  if(d2.style.opacity == '') d2.style.opacity = 1;
  // console.log(d2.style.opacity);
  if(d2.style.opacity > 0) {
    d2.style.opacity -= 0.1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(fsi);
  }
}
fsi = setInterval(fadeInter, 100);


//\//\//\// method 3
function fadeLoop() {
  var d3 = document.querySelector( ".d3" );
  if(d3.style.opacity == '') d3.style.opacity = 1;
  //console.log(d3.style.opacity);
  if(d3.style.opacity > 0) {
    d3.style.opacity -= 0.1;
  }
}
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  setTimeout(fadeLoop, i*100);
}
```

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.d2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
.d3 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class='d1'>recursive setTimeout</div>
<div class='d2'>single setInterval</div>
<div class='d3'>setTimeout in for loop</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use setTimeout to change opacity for every 100 ms, you can try this

```
setTimeout(fade,100);
setTimeout(fade,200);
setTimeout(fade,300);
...
```

or set a timing variable in loop

```
for(let timing=100,timeing<1000,timing+=100) setTimeout(fade,timing);
```

The 10 setTimeout function almost start at same time and trigger at every 100ms till 1000ms. Because it is asynchronous function, it doesn't wait for previous command to finish.